# How to check if a view controller has been dismissed in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

If I present a `ViewController` like so:

```swift
let authViewController = authUI!.authViewController()
authViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
self.present(authViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I would like to know when the `ViewController` has been dismissed. I have tried the following:

```swift
let authViewController = authUI!.authViewController()
authViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
self.present(authViewController, animated: true, completion: {
   print("View Dismissed")
})
```

but that only lets me know if the view was presented successfully. This `ViewController` was not created by me so I can't change the `viewWillDissapear` method.

Comment: If you dont have access to `authViewController` code, simplest solution would be to use `viewWillAppear` of your view controller to find when auth view controller is dismissed. Basically when you present/push any viewController over your existing view controller, your view controller's viewWillDisappear will be called similary when presented/pushed view controller is dismissed, or popped out `viewWillAppear` will be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Whole answer is predicated on an assumption that OP doesnt have access to `authViewController` code**

If you dont have access to `authViewController` code, lousy solution would be to use `viewWillAppear` of your view controller to find when auth view controller is dismissed.

Basically when you present/push any viewController over your existing view controller, your view controller's `viewWillDisappear` will be called similarly when presented/pushed view controller is dismissed, or popped out `viewWillAppear` will be called.

Because `viewWillAppear` might get called for other reasons as well and you wouldnt wanna confuse it as `authViewController` dismiss, use a boolean

```
private var shouldMonitorAuthViewControllerDismiss = false //declared a instance property
```

Set the boolean to true when you actually present the `authViewController`

```
let authViewController = authUI!.authViewController()
authViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
self.present(authViewController, animated: true, completion: {
    shouldMonitorAuthViewControllerDismiss = true
})
```

Finally in your `viewWillAppear`

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        if shouldMonitorAuthViewControllerDismiss {
            //auth view controller is dismissed
        }
        shouldMonitorAuthViewControllerDismiss = false
    }
```

Comment: I tried this solution but it appears that ```viewWillAppear``` does not run after ```authViewController``` dismissed. For context ```authViewController``` is from the FirebaseUI library.

Comment: @david: can you try `modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen` ??

Comment: @david: TBH no its not :) There is difference between `. overCurrentContext` and `. fullScreen` if you really need  `.overCurrentContext` than this solution wouldnt work :) but if its working for you am glad :) FYI this is a lousy solution knowing that you dont have access to presenting view controller :) better approach would be to have an unwind segue or have protocols set up or having callbacks (closures) if you can modify the authViewController code :) +1 to your question as well :)

Comment: I do not need to have it be ```.overCurrentContext```, what about this solution makes it non-ideal?

Comment: @david: This is the best you can do right now :) as you dont have access to AuthViewController code, if its your own VC than I would suggest adding 1. Unwind segue or 2. Have protocols and delegate set up 3.Callbacks (closures) to communicate dismmissal that way your code becomes reusable and modularized :) If this was your own VC and yet you do this solution it would obviously work but will look like a hack isnt it ? lot of people use such tricks but at the end its just a hack for me personally